# How can i achieve :success and :before with form_for?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i achieve the :before and :success with form_for ? The same way we are using it with form_remote_tag.

```
<% form_remote_tag(:url => {:controller => "test",:action => "backup"},
            :before => %($('message').innerHTML = "";Element.show('spinner')),
            :success => %(Element.hide('spinner'))) do -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular form_tag, the "success" part doesn't really mean anything (because the user will have navigated away to a different page). However, you can mimic the behavior of the "before" part as follows:

```
<% form_tag({:controller => 'test', :action => 'backup'}, {:onSubmit => %($('message').innerHTML = "";Element.show('spinner'))}) do -%>
```

Or, with form_for:

```
<% form_for @object, :html => {:onSubmit => %($('message').innerHTML = "";Element.show('spinner'))} do |f| -%>
```

Note that the user may only see the spinner for a brief second before they navigate away to the next page.

Answer (score 3):

As far as Rails 3 wants to use Unobtrusive Javascript, so putting javascript inside of your form html is bad practice now.

Now you should use observers outside your code like that:

```
$('#test_backup_form').observe('before', function(event) {
   # code
});
$('#test_backup_form').observe('success', function(event) {
   # code
});
```

etc